# Snowpark Python: how to loop over columns / execute code specific to column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I have one big table in a snowflake db which I want to split into smaller tables according to a column while flattening one column into many columns.

The big table shows animals of three categories (lion, tiger, zebra). I want to split it up into a separate lion, tiger and zebra table. On top I want to flatten a json blob (column "Details") into different columns.

How can I do that?

One way to do it is to write a user defined function with snowpark (Python), convert the table to a pandas DataFrame and then use normal Python code. I think there is a simpler way without the costly transformation to a pandas DataFrame. Maybe there even is a solution in pure SQL.

**Original table**

| Animal | Name | Details (json blob) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lion | Georg | lion key1: value1, lion key2: value2 |
| Tiger | John | tiger key1: value1, tiger key2: value2, tiger key3: value3 |
| Lion | Patrick | lion key1: value1, lion key2: value2 |
| Tiger | Sam | tiger key1: value1, tiger key2: value2, tiger key3: value3 |
| Lion | Paul | lion key1: value1, lion key2: value2 |
| Zebra | Sarah | zebra key1: value1 |

**New table: Lion table**

| Name | lion key1 | lion key2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Georg | value1 | value2 |
| Patrick | value1 | value2 |
| Paul | value1 | value2 |

**New table: tiger table**

| Name | tiger key1 | tiger key2 | tiger key3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| Sam | value1 | value2 | value3 |

**New table: zebra table**

| Name | zebra key1 |
| --- | --- |
| Sarah | value1 |

Comment: Why do you want lots of little tables instead of one big one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's setup your data so we can play with it:

```sql
create temp table all_animals as
with data as (
select split(value, '\t') x, x[0]::string animal, x[1]::string name
    , parse_json('{' || regexp_replace(x[2], '([a-z]+) key([0-9]): (value[0-9])', '"\\1_key\\2": "\\3"')  || '}') details
from table(split_to_table(
$$Lion  Georg   lion key1: value1, lion key2: value2
Tiger   John    tiger key1: value1, tiger key2: value2, tiger key3: value3
Lion    Patrick lion key1: value1, lion key2: value2
Tiger   Sam tiger key1: value1, tiger key2: value2, tiger key3: value3
Lion    Paul    lion key1: value1, lion key2: value2
Zebra   Sarah   zebra key1: value1$$
, '\n'))  
)
select * 
from data
```

[image]

Now let's create the tables where we will insert the data:

```sql
create temp table lions (name string, v1 string, v2 string);
create temp table tigers (name string, v1 string, v2 string, v3 string);
```

And now comes the answer to the question: Snowflake SQL supports conditional inserts, so we can insert each row into a different table with a different schema:

```sql
insert first
when animal='Lion' 
then into lions (name, v1, v2) values (name, details:lion_key1, details:lion_key2)
when animal='Tiger' 
then into tigers (name, v1, v2, v3) values (name, details:tiger_key1, details:tiger_key2, details:tiger_key3)
    
select *
from all_animals
;
```

As seen above, use `INSERT WHEN` to look at each row and decide into which table you'll insert them into, each with possibly a different schema.

For this solution you need to know the schema of each resulting table. If you don't know that, then we can explore in a different question how to create tables after exploring the keys to be flattened out of objects.

Comment: Great answer! Is there a a way to create tables dynamically based on the values in the "animal" column. My table contains thousands of animals. It would take a long take to create every table with a separate line of code.

Comment: "For this solution you need to know the schema of each resulting table. If you don't know that, then we can explore in a different question how to create tables after exploring the keys to be flattened out of objects."

Comment: For anybody who is also interested in how to split and flatten tables without a known schema I just asked new questions. You can find them here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73201598/snowflake-stored-procedure-split-one-table-into-several-tables-programmatical

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73201633/snowflake-stored-procedure-flatten-json-object-in-table-into-several-columns

Comment: Do you know a way to loop over column values using snowpack Python without using Pandas?