# Snowflake (stored procedure): split one table into several tables programmatically using stored procedures

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one big table in a snowflake db which I want to split into smaller tables according to a column.

The big table shows animals of three categories (lion, tiger, zebra). I want to split it up into a separate lion, tiger and zebra table programmatically (not hard coded).

How can I do that?
Ideally, I want to do it with a stored procedure inside snowflake.

Here is an example of the desired outcome. In reality I have 1000s of animals which is why the table creation process needs to be automated based on the value in the "Animal" column.

**Original table**

| Animal | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Lion | Georg |
| Tiger | John |
| Lion | Patrick |
| Tiger | Sam |
| Lion | Paul |
| Zebra | Sarah |

**New table: Lion table**

| Name |
| --- |
| Georg |
| Patrick |
| Paul |

**New table: tiger table**

| Name |
| --- |
| John |
| Sam |

**New table: zebra table**

| Name |
| --- |
| Sarah |

Comment: Note the previous question with a script to setup the data for further development https://stackoverflow.com/a/73200253/132438

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Animal VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Name   VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Animal,Name) VALUES ('Lion','Georg');
INSERT INTO mytable(Animal,Name) VALUES ('Tiger','John');
INSERT INTO mytable(Animal,Name) VALUES ('Lion','Patrick');
INSERT INTO mytable(Animal,Name) VALUES ('Tiger','Sam');
INSERT INTO mytable(Animal,Name) VALUES ('Lion','Paul');
INSERT INTO mytable(Animal,Name) VALUES ('Zebra','Sarah');
```

You can use Snowflake scripting to generate these tables:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_tables()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
   srctable VARCHAR := 'mytable';
   c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT Animal FROM mytable;
BEGIN
   FOR c IN c1 DO
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || c.Animal || ' AS SELECT Name FROM ' || srctable || ' WHERE Animal = ''' || c.Animal || '''';
   END FOR;
   RETURN 'OK';
END;

call generate_tables();
```

It generates the tables:

```
Select * from lion;

Select * from Tiger;

Select * from Zebra;
```